# MongoDB: Problems using $concat to update the value of a field

Tags: mongodb, concatenation

I'm trying to update the value of a field in a MongoDB collection by concatenating it with a literal string. Besides this, the field is an integer, and I want to add a "0" in front, so it will became a string.

I've read that I can't use the old value of the field in a single update instruction, so I'm using a **forEach()** method.

Here is the code:

```
db.col_1.find({"field_1": {$lt: 10000}}).forEach( function(i){
  db.col_1.update({_id: i._id},
    {$set: { "field_1": {$concat: ["0", i.field_1]}}} 
    )
});
```

The return result is :

```
The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concat' in 'field_1.$concat' is not valid for storage.
```

I'm sure I'm not writting the $concat command properly, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `{$set: { "field_1": "0" + i.field_1 } }`

Comment: $concat can only be used in aggregation queries

Comment: @chridam -- It works perfectly well like this, thank you very much!

Comment: Answer posted. Please approve and upvote my answer if you like my effort

Answer (score 10):

$concat is an aggregation pipeline, not an update operator/modifier.

It seems that what you're trying to do can be achieved by doing the following:

```
db.col_1
  .find({ "field_1": { $lt: 10000 } })
  .forEach( function(i) {
    db.col_1.update(
      { _id: i._id },
      { $set: { "field_1": "0" + i.field_1 } }
    )
   });
```

Answer (score 6):

To update the MongoDB field using the value of another field for **MongoDB version 4.2** also introduced the $set pipeline stage operator which is an alias for $addFields. You can use $set here as it maps with what we are trying to achieve.

```
let query = {
    "field_1": {
        $lt: 10000
    }
};
let changes = {
    $set: {
        "field_1": {
            "$concat": ["0", "$field_1"]
        }
    }
};
let UpdatedStatus = await col_1.updateMany(query, [changes]).lean();
console.log(UpdatedStatus);
```

Comment: No need for using time taking looping process

Comment: I didn't know we could use pipelines in update operations just like with aggregations, the more I know mongodb, the more I like it!

Comment: This will not work, you cannot use $concat in an insert/update statement

Comment: from version  4.2 u can use aggregate operators in update  with  changes in array [] instead of object{}

Comment: This is by far the best option. Thanks. you also solved the problem of the need to pass the "change" part with "[ ]" parenthesis. Note, you can also add "toString" to the contact option: "$concat": [value, "_", {"$toString": "$_id"}].

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way if you want to use $set with $concat:

```
db.col_1.updateMany(
    {"field_1": {$lt: 10000}},
    [
        { $set: { "field_1": {$concat: ["0", "$field_1"]} } }
    ]
 )
```

You don't need to use `forEach`. With `updateMany`, you can easily modify all the documents that match the query `{"field_1": {$lt: 10000}}`.