# Update string field concatenating another string in mongodb with spring-data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How I can update a string field in a mongo document, concatenating another string value, using java and spring-data mongo? Ex:

```
{
    “languages”: “python,java,c”
}
```

Concat “kotlin”:

```
{
    “languages”: “python,java,c,kotlin”
}
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Does the below link answers your question? [mongodb-problems-using-concat-to-update-the-value-of-a-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674996/mongodb-problems-using-concat-to-update-the-value-of-a-field)

Comment: Not really, I did check that question and it not answer mine, because I have the javascript code and works fine, but I haven’t the java code with spring-data.

Answer (score 3):

> Starting in MongoDB `v4.2`, the `db.collection.update()` method can accept an [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/index.html) to modify a field using the values of the other fields in the Document.

[Update with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline)

Try this one:

```
UpdateResult result = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(Query.query(new Criteria()),
    AggregationUpdate.update()
        .set(SetOperation.set("languages")
                .toValue(StringOperators.Concat.valueOf("languages").concat(",").concat("kotlin"))),
    "collection"); //mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Entity.class)
System.out.println(result);
//AcknowledgedUpdateResult{matchedCount=1, modifiedCount=1, upsertedId=null}
```

In MongoDB shell, it looks like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
  [
    { "$set" : { "languages" : { "$concat" : ["$languages", ",", "kotlin"]}}}
  ]
)
```