# Update inner Array element property using outer field value Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection as below and I wish to update the email with "@company.com" where type is "email" and Details is null.

```
{
 "Name" : "Sam",
"Company" : "Awesomeness"
 "Contacts" : [
 {    
   "type" : "phone",
   "Detail" : "1231232" 
 },
{
  "type" : "email",
  "Detail" : null
} 
]
}
```

I have reached as far as

```
   collection.update({"Contacts.type" : "email", "Contacts.Detail" : null}, 
    { $set : 
      { "Contacts.$.Detail" : 
            { 
              $concat : [$Name , "@" , "$Company", ".com"] 
            }
     })
```

but this gives an error saying $ dollar prefixed field "$concat" ....is not valid for storage.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674996/mongodb-problems-using-concat-to-update-the-value-of-a-field. `$concat` is an operator used in aggregation pipelines, you can't use it when doing an update.

Comment: Ok. But then is there any other solution to the problem mentioned ?

Comment: Does the accepted answer of the post I linked not help?

Comment: Not exactly, you see I want to update the field in an inner array (email) and not outer (like company). The can I have a forEach inside of forEach and then an update ?